# How to create components for an electronics circuit simulator

Tags: javascript

I am creating a circuit simulator as a project and i have started by making all the UI etc to get it to a functioning stage however I have hit a mental block in my work, I currently have a list of components (in the form of an accordion if that is relevant) on my website. Now what I am confused about is how I can make these components. I am using JavaScript as I am sure that is relevant information to have.

So what i want it to do is when I click on the component I want in the list how can i get it so that component appears under my mouse and can be dragged and dropped around the screen and some of them edited. I am really struggling to think of a way to do this so any help would really be appreciated.

If any more information/detail or screenshots and code is needed please ask I will be more that happy to provide anything if i can get some help with this.

Edit: Thanks for the answers guys it's really appreciated!

Comment: Code is welcome and needed, do post it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to clone/create the html element that represent the component then allow it to be 'dragged' into place.

Comment: This is one of those times where inventing it yourself is really going to take too much time and probably going to not work very well. You really need a library to take advantage of here, and at risk of people hating a jQuery suggestion, the jQuery UI provides a very easy way to integrate drag and drop functionality into your site. https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: You need to look at using jQuery (https://jquery.com/) and jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/) to create draggable elements - https://jqueryui.com/draggable/.

Comment: Have you looked at jquery draggable ? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/wJUHF/7/

Comment: Wow this is really amazing i didn't expect so many responses so soon, I will look in more depth about what I can do with the jQueryUI, and thank you especially to Chris as that is really useful for me and is very similar to what I am looking for! The only thing is I need to think (component) you are moving to not be an exact replica of what you originally click if that makes sense and I will also need them to be able to be joined together via 'wires'! which I imagine is going to be very hard, but this is a great start and really helps me out. Thanks again everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: @ChrisMoutray I only just realized that it would allow me to reference you so you know I replied, (Not very clever of me sorry!) But thank you for your response I do have a couple of questions about the code itself, however most of it i seem to have been able to understand with the help of your comments so thank you for that. If you wouldn't mind answering some queries I have about it then please let me know as I would be very interested in asking them.

Comment: Beneficial-tip at one stage of development---> When you click on the draggable item. You should detect the item clicked (using document.getElementById("some_id").value) and get that items value and then assign that specific unique value to a global/local variable. When you do that, you should maintain all the information of an object in a javascript-object.
Take time and build the logic. It is possible. Good-luck. @Liam

Comment: @MalikAsifComsats Hey, thank you for your comment, it has pointed me in the right direction of the things to work on to get this going. I really appreciate it! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

This post has been up for a couple of years but here is a good start for you.
    https://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/78jwe/

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$('.drop-zone').droppable({
    accept: '.drag',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
        if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
            $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
                containment: '.drop-zone'
            }));
        }
    }
});

$('.drag').draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});

});
```